# htaccess, URL rewriting and redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, redirect, http-status-code-301

I looked for this in stack overflow but don't find any relevant answer:

I have an htaccess file with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R,NE]

RewriteRule ^home$  /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home$  /index.php?content=home [L]
RewriteRule ^accueil$  /index.php?content=home&lang=fr [L]
RewriteRule ^home$  /index.php?content=home&lang=en [L]

RewriteRule ^acceuil-message-1$  /index.php?content=home&val=1&lang=fr [L]
RewriteRule ^home-notice-1$  /index.php?content=home&val=1&lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^acceuil-message-2$  /index.php?content=home&val=2&lang=fr [L]
RewriteRule ^home-notice-2$  /index.php?content=home&val=2&lang=en [L]

RewriteRule ^news-a-la-une$  /index.php?content=news&mode=featured&lang=fr [L]
RewriteRule ^featured-news$  /index.php?content=news&mode=featured&lang=en [L]

RewriteRule ^news-recentes-([0-9]+)$  /index.php?content=news&mode=list&page=$1&lang=fr [L]
RewriteRule ^latest-news-([0-9]+)$  /index.php?content=news&mode=list&page=$1&lang=en [L]
...
```

It works fine.

But I need to set up a 301 redirection.
So, I just changed every [L] to [R=301,L]

But when I do so, my URL's are back like they were before on the browser.

I presume that the redirection is applied twice which would explain why I don't have any error message while still having the old urls showing up, but I don't know then where to apply the [R=301,L] and where not to in order to make it work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You try to mix redirect and rewrite. You don't need `301` if you just rewrite the URL. The "long" url will not be visible. `301` is useful if you move a page to another location, but I don't think it's what you try to do here.

Comment: Thank you sonique. In fact I want to rewrite the URL's but I also need to redirect as I need the Google searches not to point to the previous URL's of the website anymore. I read almost everywhere that the 301 redirection is the way to go for this. So, what should I do to make this file do what I need it to do? Thanks.

Comment: So what is the previous URL ? the one with `index.php?....`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your question. These previous url's are clearly visible in the htaccess sample here above, aren't they (index.php?content=...)?

Answer (score 0):

So you have to redirect 301 as following in addition to the RewriteRules:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php$ /home [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php?content=home&val=([0-9]+)&lang=fr /acceuil-message-1$ [L]
```

PS: you have a type in `acceuil` it should say `accueil`

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Reference: http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/accueil/569

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try that and if it works for me, I'll come back and vote for your answer.

Comment: Query string is not part of match in mod-alias, so your 2nd example wont work. also the [L] , Reread the mod-alias documentation : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch